# Flash AS3: How to disable the keyboard controls of MC 1, when MC 2 is clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two different movieclips that can be moved with the same keyboard keys.

How do I disable the keyboard controls of movieclip 1, when movieclip 2 is clicked
and vice versa?

Code:

```
movieclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMcClick);
function onMcClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
    movieclip = target;
}

var speed:Number = 1.0;
var leftArrow:Boolean=false;
var rightArrow:Boolean=false;
var upArrow:Boolean=false;
var downArrow:Boolean=false;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObject);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHit);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, noKeyHit);

function keyHit(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = true;
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = true;
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = true;
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = true;
}


function noKeyHit2(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) leftArrow = false; 
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) rightArrow = false; 
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) upArrow = false;
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) downArrow = false;
}

function moveObject(e:Event):void
{
    if(leftArrow) movieclip.rotation -=0.75;
    if(rightArrow) movieclip.rotation +=0.75;
    if(upArrow) movieclip.scaleY +=0.01
    if(downArrow) movieclip.scaleY -=0.01;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that simply add the click event listener to your both movie clips and every time select the clicked one as `movieclip` (global var) :

```
var movieclip:MovieClip = null;

mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMcClick);
mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMcClick);
function onMcClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    movieclip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
}
```

That's all.

Hope that can help.

Comment: I added the eventlisteners.But when I click and rotate mc1 with arrow keys,
and then click mc2 to see if mc1 stops rotating, it doesn't.

Comment: @New2AS3 According to your posted code, my code should give you the behavior that you want. Could you show how did you edited your code (you can use pastebin.com if you don't want to edit your post) ?

Comment: The code I posted was only some of the code in my project, so that might be  why it isn't working. http://pastebin.com/vRL4NZLw (all the code from the project is there + the event listeners.

Comment: @New2AS3 You've duplicated the same code inside the click handlers of your movieclips and this is wrong, you have to use only one click handler for both movieclips and you do what you want according to the pressed one ...